# Can execute binary, but not using "source"

Tags: bash, shell, jobs, watch

Trying to get `watch jobs` to work.  This is tricky because `jobs` reports jobs owned by the current shell, and `watch` creates another shell. Therefore I would like to run `. watch jobs` or `source watch jobs`, but I get this error:

```
-bash: source: /usr/bin/watch: cannot execute binary file
```

Here is the output of `file /usr/bin/watch`:

```
/usr/bin/watch: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.15, BuildID[sha1]=0xe207fd209faf781a58f5f30922c99da759bd3953, stripped
```

How to debug `source` in this case?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can only `source` scripts, not executables. Try:

```
while true; do clear; jobs; sleep 2; done
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot source in a binary file in shell, it is meant for shell scripts only.

`source command` is used for executing a shell script in current process only, without forking a new sub-shell process.